# Extruder motor moves in the wrong direction

Tags: extruder, zonestar-z9v5-pro

The extruder motors of my Zonestar Z9V5 Pro are rotating in the wrong direction, removing the filaments instead of pushing. Someone can help me solve this. Software is up to date.

Comment: Hi Leo, welcome to SE.3DPrinting! Have you seen this question: ["Extruder is running backwards?"](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/extruder-is-running-backwards), if this is the same question we can close this for being a duplicate. If not please provide more information on what you did to the printer why it is now spinning the wrong direction!